# Spree or Solidus - Filter Product Taxons - taxons.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, spree, solidus

Let's say I have 3 Taxons (Builders, States, Services). Is there a way to Filter "Edit Product Taxons" to list, when clicked, only "Services" Taxon in the dropdown? The spree view is edit_product.html.erb

Thanks

```
taxons.js
//= require solidus_admin/Sortable
Spree.ready(function() {
  var productTemplate = HandlebarsTemplates['products/sortable'];
  var productListTemplate = function(products) {
    return _.map(products, productTemplate).join('') || "<h4>" + Spree.translations.no_results + "</h4>";
  };

  var saveSort = function(e) {
    var item = e.item;
    Spree.ajax({
      url: Spree.routes.classifications_api,
      method: 'PUT',
      data: {
        product_id: item.getAttribute('data-product-id'),
        taxon_id: $('#taxon_id').val(),
        position: e.newIndex
      }
    });
  };

  var formatTaxon = function(taxon) {
    return Select2.util.escapeMarkup(taxon.pretty_name);
  };

  $('#taxon_id').select2({
    dropdownCssClass: "taxon_select_box",
    placeholder: Spree.translations.find_a_taxon,
    ajax: {
      url: Spree.routes.taxons_search,
      params: {
        "headers": {
          "X-Spree-Token": Spree.api_key
        }
      },
      data: function(term, page) {
        return {
          per_page: 50,
          page: page,
          q: {
            name_cont: term
          }
        };
      },
      results: function(data) {
        return {
          results: data['taxons'],
          more: data.current_page < data.pages
        };
      }
    },
    formatResult: formatTaxon,
    formatSelection: formatTaxon
  });

  $('#taxon_id').on("change", function(e) {
    Spree.ajax({
      url: Spree.routes.taxon_products_api,
      data: {
        id: e.val,
        simple: 1
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#taxon_products').html(productListTemplate(data.products));

        var el = document.querySelector('#taxon_products')

        new Sortable(el, {
          draggable: ".sort_item",
          onEnd: saveSort
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The above JS applies to Spree or Solidus  e-commerce platforms.

Would like to be able to filter taxons to include name "Services".

To clarify:
Let's say I have "Builders, States and Services" taxonomies. In Admin Edit Product, all Taxons for builders, states, and services are listed in the dropdown list.

I would like to be able to filter which taxonomies get listed. In this case, I would like the dropdown list box to list only "**Services**" taxons.

```
**Would like to see this:**
Services -> Senior Care
Services -> Nurse

**Do not want this:**
Builders -> Wall
Builders-> Mason
Services -> Senior Care
Services -> Nurse
States -> Utah
States -> Texas
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this work by modifying taxon_autocomplete.js